# scraping website using python or wget - awaiting response problem

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, urllib, wget

I am trying to download more than 300k HTML files from the same server. I have the URLs in a list/text file. My first attempt was to use python urllib/requests but it was incredibly slow and would get stuck after a few links (10-20). Code example:

```
for i, url in enumerate(url_list):
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, "./pages/"+str(i))
```

Then I tried simply using wget like this:

`wget -i links_file.txt -U netscape`

wget works great and it downloads between 1-5 k files without problems and seems very fast but then gets stuck at random (?) files:

`Connecting to <website>... connected. HTTP request sent, awaiting response...`

Now I can see at which URL it got stuck and just stop the run and start it again from the same point and it works perfectly fine again for another 1-5k downloads. Since I can't do this manually every time it gets stuck until I finally have all 300k files, I was wondering if there is a way how I can stop wget automatically if it awaits a response for too long and then just tries again? Or is there any other/better way to download this many HTML files automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how I can stop wget automatically if it awaits a response for too long
> and then just tries again?

What you are looking for is called *timeout* and number of *retries*. In [`wget`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/wget.1.html) you might use `--timeout` to set all timeouts at once or use specific timeouts that is

```
--dns-timeout
--connect-timeout
--read-timeout
```

In either case you should provide value as number of seconds after `=` for example `--timeout=60`

Use `--tries` to set number of retries (default: 20), for example `--tries=10` but keep in mind that in case of fatal error no retry is done.

You might also find useful `--no-clobber` which effect is that file is not downloaded if already exist such named file (which would be overwritten)

Comment: Thank you I tied these options before, but I think I see were my problem was. That was helpful. I also found another solution of just running wget in a python loop and that ignores the errors and just jumps to the next URL.